# Is Hollywood Bowl for blackberry written in J2ME or Webworks?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

[Hollywood Bowl](http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/12338?lang=en) looks modern yet it is compatible with most of the devices which is making me think it is a web works app. Any thoughts?

Comment: My initial guess from reading the description and seeing the file size is that it's a java app, but I'd email the vendor to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a Java app. But as mentioned in one of the comments, the best way to find out is to email the developer :)